# Coupled Line Bandpass Filter

Tags: rf, band-pass, microstrip

I am trying to design a microstrip bandpass filter in ADS with a center frequency of 2.4GHz and a fractional BW of 10%. My results from the schematic look great:
[image]

When I move to the layout and EM simulation, my results look nothing close to a bandpass filter. I am not sure if it is something with my setup or the physical layout. The schematic and layout is shown below:
[image]

[image]

The results from the EM simulation are here:
[image]

I was thinking it could be with how close the spacing is between the coupled lines, but if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is out of my field. but a guy that is true scientist makes those lines little bit different, surely there are also exact formulas, but I was not his student. Look for some his examples: http://s53mv.s5tech.net/cavity/cavity.html  http://s53mv.s5tech.net/zifssb/block.html http://s53mv.s5tech.net/zifssb/lscband.html

Comment: I don't have the resources to use a cavity

Comment: Your first and last couple sections look like they have no gap at all. I don't know why, but that is almost surely the problem.

Comment: Make sure the mesh size in your EM simulation is smaller than the 50 um gap you are trying to model.

Comment: Only the 1st link is about the cavity. It always uses at least 4 strips, two with small gap and between other two a larger gap. And also tells that different PCB materials behave different, everything is in boxed with a kind of absorber foam.

Answer (score 0):

EM simulation is to pick cells per wave length.  Typical filter centered at 10 GHz , then choose meshing at 20 Ghz and 50 cells per wavelegth